# php to get session variable name from php.ini

Tags: php, session, sessionid

Can we get variable name('PHPSESSID') defined php.ini through some function in PHP?

I know it is constant through the php.ini

But in case if it has been changed. How to get the name dynamically?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [session_name()](http://az.php.net/session_name) function